# Windows Batch Check Hostname Exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, hosts

I want to check if a hostname exists on my PC (ie found in `hosts` file under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`).

Is there a way to find if it exist using a batch command or some other way?

Comment: Edit your question and post something that did you tried until now ! and add more details to describe your aim !

Comment: The thing is I don't know from where to start as it is a first time for me writing a batch file, but I googled my question first and results said to connect to it, but I want to avoid that and just check if it exists or not

Comment: Did you mean that you would like to check if the URL exists on your hosts file or not ?

Comment: In my `hosts` file if I have `127.0.0.1 localhost` I just want to check if "localhost" exists or not

Comment: I was thinking or reading the file and looking for the string I want, but I wanted to know if there is a command that just checks without me having to read the hosts file and searching for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try for this batch file with some extra info :

```
@echo off
set "SearchString=localhost"
set "LogFile=%userprofile%\Desktop\LogFile.txt"
set "hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
(
    Echo  **************************** General info ****************************
    Echo Running under: %username% on profile: %userprofile%
    Echo Computer name: %computername%
    Echo Operating System:
    wmic os get caption | findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"^Caption"
    Echo Boot Mode:
    wmic COMPUTERSYSTEM GET BootupState | find "boot"
    Echo Antivirus software installed:
    wmic /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName | findstr /v /r /c:"^$" /c:"displayName"
    Echo Executed on: %date% @ %time%
    Echo  ********************* Hosts' File Contents with the string "%SearchString%" ************************
)>"%LogFile%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%hostspath%" ^| find /I "%SearchString%"') Do (
     echo %%a >> "%LogFile%"
)
Start "" "%LogFile%"
```

Comment: Thanks Hackoo but could you explain to me how is the search done, I am learning batch scripting so I want to know how it is done.
Btw, this will not create the file if the hostname does not exist so I can check if the file eixsts or not to know if the hostname exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

Easier and more robust solution

url.bat:

```
@echo off

set url=%1
ping -n 1 %url% > nul 2> nul
if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
 echo %url% exists
) else (
 echo %url% does not exist
)
```

Test

```
> url.bat google.com
google.com exists

> url.bat google.commmmmm
google.commmmmm does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

What you possibly can do is pinging the hostname you are looking for and then check for certain strings, that will show you if the hostname could be found or not. Would look like this (I guess):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p input= "Hostname"
set hostexists=yes
For /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !input!') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xFOO" if "x%%b"=="xBAR" set hostexists=no
)
If "x!hostexists!"=="xno" (
echo. "Does not exist"
) ELSE (
echo. "Does exist"
Pause
```

Basic thought is that when you try to ping a hostname that is not available, you will get a specific output from the commandline. Try it yourself: Open the cmd.exe (Hit the Windows-Button +R and type `cmd`) and in the commandline write `ping foobar` and wait a bit. You should get a message like: Ping-Request could not find "foobar" [...]. You take the first two words and put them into the code: 1st word to `FOO` and 2nd to `BAR`.

The program will look into the output of the ping command and place the first two words (=tokens) in `%%a` and `%%b` checking if they are equal to the desired words, marking the host does not exist.

I hope this will help :) Not sure if that is what you wanted :D

Greetings

geisterfurz007